# uid in Firebase not unique

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I am developing a new app, that uses firebase as a backend.

Everything works well, however, I am frustrated by the fact that their documentation says that a user's uid is "the user's unique key across all providers." when that is clearly not the case. Every provider has a different scheme for creating uids - or am I missing something?

Examples:

facebook uid: "facebook:123456789012345"

username/password uid: "b30e4ffa-73f7-4fdb-b536-a9d193b12a8d"

Please update your documentation, or fix it. Thank you.

Comment: If you'd like to file a bug report, firebase-support@google.com is probably a better spot. But in this case, I'm not sure what the problem is. In the samples you provide, the `uid` is unique across all providers.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for your comment. It seems that I've been misunderstanding the wording. I thought it was unique in the sense that it would be the same, no matter if the same user used facebook, password or something else. Thank you for getting me to understand, and thank you for an awesome product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I've been misunderstanding the wording. I thought it was unique in the sense that it would be the same, no matter if the same user used facebook, password or something else.

But it just means that all providers generate unique ids, and no collisions between providers will ever occur.